# Wso2 Dss feature installation on Wso2 ESB 4.8.1 showing error

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I am working on wso2 esb 4.8.1 for creating for creating proxy services , for the services which i have hosted on Wso2 Dss on another server. Recently i have read about we can install wso2 dss feature itself in esb by installing Data service Hosting 3.2.3 from online repository

**http://dist.wso2.org/p2/carbon/releases/turing** . But during installation it shows following error

what can i do , to install dss on esb. Or otherwise how can i use both in same server creating like

creating webservices in dss and proxy services in Esb of WSOL2

> "Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
>   Software being installed: Data Service Hosting Feature 4.2.3
>   (org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.feature.group 4.2.3) Software currently
>   installed: WSO2 Carbon - New Datasource Management Feature 4.2.0
>   (org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.feature.group 4.2.0) Only one of the
>   following can be installed at once: WSO2 Carbon - New Datasource
>   Management UI Feature 4.2.2
>   (org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.ui.feature.jar 4.2.2) WSO2 Carbon - New
>   Datasource Management UI Feature 4.2.0
>   (org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.ui.feature.jar 4.2.0) Cannot satisfy
>   dependency: From: Data Service Hosting Feature 4.2.3
>   (org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.feature.group 4.2.3) To:
>   org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.ui.feature.group [4.2.3] Cannot satisfy
>   dependency: From: Data Service Hosting UI Feature 4.2.3
>   (org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.ui.feature.group 4.2.3) To:
>   org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.ui.feature.group [4.2.2,4.3.0) Cannot
>   satisfy dependency: From: WSO2 Carbon - New Datasource Management
>   Feature 4.2.0 (org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.feature.group 4.2.0) To:
>   org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.ui.feature.group [4.2.0] Cannot satisfy
>   dependency: From: WSO2 Carbon - New Datasource Management UI Feature
>   4.2.0 (org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.ui.feature.group 4.2.0) To: org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.ui.feature.jar [4.2.0] Cannot satisfy
>   dependency: From: WSO2 Carbon - New Datasource Management UI Feature
>   4.2.2 (org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.ui.feature.group 4.2.2) To: org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.ui.feature.jar [4.2.2]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Install the complete Data Services Hosting Feature from the root level in the tree. You can tick the "Group By Category" checkbox when listing the features list.

Comment: Thank u , Yeah its fixed now.So i have both data services and proxy services in ESB which i have hosted in my server. But when i restart the server the proxy services belongs to the data service WSDL url which is in same server is not loading.It shows Proxy refers wsdl url is unavailable .What may be the issue

Comment: For Installing BAM Mediator Aggregate Same Problem is occuring what can i do , i cannot find BAM Mediator when i tick Group By Category